# TortoiseGit no commit option in context menu

Tags: tortoisegit

TortoiseGit installed.
Git Windows installed.

1. I created a new repository in Bitbucket.
2. git init
3. git remote add origin https:// etc.
4. Created a small file.
5. In File Explorer, right-click file, TortoiseGit -> Add.
6. In File Explorer, right-click parent subdirectory, TortoiseGit -> (no commit menu option).

How does one commit a file using the context menu for TortoiseGit?

Comment: How does the context menu look like?

Comment: It's very long, with Pull, Fetch, Push at the top... and Settings, Help and About at the bottom. Nowhere is there "Commit." So, I can't get the commit dialog up that I see in TortoiseGit help stuff.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot - normally the commit entry is not in the TortoiseGit subentry but directly above the "TortoiseGit" entry in the context menu

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that command (Git Commit -> master) just above TortoiseGit. However, even though that shows my file, shows that it's been added, and the file is checked, the OK button is not enabled--all I can do is Cancel. I can't take a screen shot, I'm a Linux guy and can't find a way to make the Snipping Tool take a snapshot while the context menus are up.

Comment: You need to enter a commit message.

Comment: So obvious. Thank you. I'm a Linux command-line guy trying to set someone up in Windows. Need to grow a brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following screenshot of a context menu. The TortoiseGit commit entry is directly above the TortoiseGit submenu entry.

[image]

Please beware, that the TortoiseGit menu is configurable and you can hide entries. Hold the shift-key while opening the context menu to see all available commands.

Comment: Thanks. Ii assumed that item was Git and not TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, without shift-key I could not see Commit in any of the menus.
I found out that in Settings, I have it checked in both context menu and context menu 2. When I unchecked it to be only at one place, it was fixed.